How to combine 3 annotated datasets into one file for further processing?
I have a dataset annotated by three people, so now I have three files. This dataset is about tweets annotation. How can I combine this dataset into one file for further processing.  The data set is an excel file and contains five columns:
name tweet id PPP,PTI,PMLN, full text

The annotations are done on pti,pmln each column of annotation is 0.1,-1 value
I want to export a new file combing through a voting classifier or something like this

You could use pandas to merge them all together into one and export at the end.  Would be good to see a minimal reproducible example of the data in your question, and what you have tried so far to do this

The easiest way is to use pandas ability to merge dataframes.
# Importing packages
import pandas as pd
import os

# Write the files you wish to combine
files = ['first.xlsx', 'second.xlsx', 'third.xlsx']

# Loop over the filenames and import each as a dataframe in a new list
dfs = []
for file in files: dfs.append( pd.read_excel(file) )

# Merge each into a new dataframe
df_merged = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

# Write the new dataframe to a new file (make sure it does not overwrite some already existing file)
save_file = 'final.xlsx'
if not os.path.exists(save_file):
    df_merged.to_excel(save_file, index=False)
else:
    print("Cannot overwrtie already existing file")

This assumes that you have the written the excel in a "normal" way as for example:
An example of a "normal" excel
